# Не горит светодиод rgb в схеме Proteus-a?

Tags: c, stm32, микроконтроллеры, proteus

В программе не получается зажечь rgb светодиод? Код скорее всего верный, в чем ошибка подключения?

```
void set_rgb (uint8_t red, uint8_t blue, uint8_t green)
    {
        htim1.Instance->CCR1 = red;
        htim1.Instance->CCR2 = blue;
        htim1.Instance->CCR3 = green;
    }
```

//----------------------------------------------------------------

```
HAL_TIM_PWM_Start (&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
HAL_TIM_PWM_Start (&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_2);
HAL_TIM_PWM_Start (&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_3);
```

[image: Окно Протеуса]